# Select between two dynamic (variable) dates SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query that runs once a day that I would like to share however I need to remove the part where the other users in my team will have to edit it. Essentially, it's run Monday thru Friday. I want, if today is Monday, give me the last 3 days worth of data. Any other day, just give me yesterday's data.

So far this is what I have:

Update: They are all strings, so now I get the following error.

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BETWEEN'."

```
DECLARE @daychecker varchar(max) = FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dddd')
DECLARE @daterange0 varchar(max)
DECLARE @daterange1 varchar(max) = FORMAT(GETDATE()-3, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
DECLARE @daterange2 varchar(max) = FORMAT(GETDATE()-1, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    IF  @daychecker = 'Wednesday'
        BEGIN
        SET @daterange0 = BETWEEN @daterange1 AND @daterange2
    END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @daterange0 = FORMAT(GETDATE()-1, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    END
SELECT @daterange0;
```

The result for today as an example should return yesterday's date. But that doesn't work. I will consider all options including hardcoding some sort of master start date that we can count from like maybe the start of the year or something.

Comment: `SET @daterange0 = BETWEEN @daterange1 AND @daterange2` is not valid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're much better off defining 2 dates, a start date and end date, and filtering your query based on them. EDIT: I'm now unsure if you want actual dates for filtering data, or a label for a report. I modified my answer to include the latter, use whichever you want and ignore the other ...

```
DECLARE @DateStart DATE 
DECLARE @DateEnd DATE 
DECLARE @LableRange varchar(max)
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) --Sun=1, Mon=2, ...
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 2 BEGIN
    SET @DateStart = DATEADD (DAY, -5,GETDATE())
    SET @DateEnd = DATEADD (DAY, -2,GETDATE())
    SET @LableRange = CONCAT(FORMAT(@DateStart, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), ', '
      , FORMAT(DATEADD(day,1,@DateStart), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), ', '
      , FORMAT(DATEADD(day,2,@DateStart), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
   -- or maybe this format is better
   --SET @LableRange = CONCAT('BETWEEN '
      --, FORMAT(@DateStart, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), ' AND '
      --, FORMAT(DATEADD(day,2,@DateStart), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @DateStart = DATEADD (DAY, -1,GETDATE())
    SET @DateEnd = GETDATE()
    SET @LableRange = FORMAT(@DateStart, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
END

SELECT @LableRange

SELECT * FROM SomeTable as T
WHERE T.TestDate < @DateEnd AND T.TestDate >= @DateStart
```

Note that this works even if the date you are filtering on is a datetime instead of pure date.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, except that the start date of the week is a config value, so you need to make sure you check for that

Comment: True, thanks Neville! Yes, the setting is unlikely to change, but it might be set to have the week start on Monday, in which case my test should be = 1 instead of = 2.

Comment: Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, GetDate() ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Comment: Yeah I ran it and simply returned the #4 (which is wednesday). I need it to return 3 values when the first condition is satisfied. That is, in the code snippet above, it should give me 1,2,3 (sun, mon, tue).

Comment: OK, I modified it to include a label describing the date, maybe that label was all you wanted? If so, you can drop the @DateEnd variable